# Is it possible to create dataverse table dynamically from power automate

Tags: power-automate, dataverse, power-platform

I want to create dataverse table dynamically using power automate flow.For that I am using http connector in the power automate flow but I am facing issue as 'invalid http'.Please advise if power automate can do this or I would need something else to achieve this objective.The below code which I am trying is from Microsoft article -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/create-update-entity-definitions-using-web-api#create-table-definitions

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.2/EntityDefinitions HTTP/1.1
MSCRM.SolutionUniqueName: examplesolution
Accept: application/json  
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8  
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0  
OData-Version: 4.0  
  
{  
  "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.EntityMetadata",  
 "Attributes": [  
  {  
   "AttributeType": "String",  
   "AttributeTypeName": {  
    "Value": "StringType"  
   },  
   "Description": {  
     "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",  
    "LocalizedLabels": [  
     {  
       "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",  
      "Label": "Type the name of the bank account",  
      "LanguageCode": 1033  
     }  
    ]  
   },  
   "DisplayName": {  
     "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",  
    "LocalizedLabels": [  
     {  
       "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",  
      "Label": "Account Name",  
      "LanguageCode": 1033  
     }  
    ]  
   },  
   "IsPrimaryName": true,  
   "RequiredLevel": {  
    "Value": "None",  
    "CanBeChanged": true,  
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifyrequirementlevelsettings"  
   },  
   "SchemaName": "new_AccountName",  
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.StringAttributeMetadata",  
   "FormatName": {  
    "Value": "Text"  
   },  
   "MaxLength": 100  
  }  
 ],  
 "Description": {  
   "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",  
  "LocalizedLabels": [  
   {  
     "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",  
    "Label": "An entity to store information about customer bank accounts",  
    "LanguageCode": 1033  
   }  
  ]  
 },  
 "DisplayCollectionName": {  
   "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",  
  "LocalizedLabels": [  
   {  
     "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",  
    "Label": "Bank Accounts",  
    "LanguageCode": 1033  
   }  
  ]  
 },  
 "DisplayName": {  
   "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",  
  "LocalizedLabels": [  
   {  
     "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",  
    "Label": "Bank Account",  
    "LanguageCode": 1033  
   }  
  ]  
 },  
 "HasActivities": false,  
 "HasNotes": false,  
 "IsActivity": false,  
 "OwnershipType": "UserOwned",  
 "SchemaName": "new_BankAccount"  
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us a screenshot of your error. It will be possible, it’s just a HTTP call. Also, show us the HTTP step as it’s defined.

Comment: @Skin - the content in body shows error - "http contains invalid expression"

Answer (score 0):

Your issues is, `@` signs in PowerAutomate are reserved characters because they’re used to indicate the beginning of an expression.

To get around this, instead of just placing the `@` sign directly in the string, you need to encase the `@` in an expression, like thus ...

```
string('@')
```

You can embed an expression within direct text, no need to concatenate everything together with an expression.

I trust that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue. string('@') did not work but replacing @ with @@ worked.

Comment: My answer does work, I’ve used it before. You need to enter it as an expression, you likely didn’t do that. Handy to know that @@ works.